# how can I use kali linux (wsl2) and android (bluestacks) on windows 10

Tags: virtual-machine, kali-linux, bluestacks

I download kali linux on the microsoft store and enable virtualization and then I had kali linux, after I download bluestacks, it had a weird error so I unnistalled and installed again, and it worked, but now I cant use Kali Linux, it says:

```
Enable the Windows Virtual Machine Platform feature and verify that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS.
For more information, visit https://aka.ms/wsl2-install
```

What can I do for use both?

Win version: 2004 build 19041.630 home single language

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  Do you have **Virtual Machine Platform** enabled.  Hyper-V is not required.  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: What other optional Windows features do you have installed?

Comment: now I enabled virtual machine platform and I cant use bluestacks, and can use kali linux

Comment: @Ramhound probably just virtualization stuff

Comment: I need to know what features exactly you have enabled.  What you "probably" have enabled isn't helpful.  Instead of submitting temporary commentary, you should edit your question instead.

Comment: how can i see what features I have enabled exactly?

Comment: Through `Turn Windows features on or off` or through PowerShell using the appropriate command.

Comment: If Bluestacks has not been updated to be compatible with Virtual Machine Platform then there is nothing you can do.  You won't be able to use WSL2 and Bluestacks on the same machine.  **I only know about WSL2.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you can only have one VM-based application running at a time. If you look at your Task Manager, I'm willing to bet there's a hung process for either BlueStacks or the Kali image you're trying to run.

If you're running Windows 10 Home, that's most likely your problem altogether.